# cookies on GetServerSideProps first load comes undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cookies, next.js13

The error I'm having is that after executing the login endpoint call and successfully registering a token cookie as follows:

```
setCookie(undefined, "nextauth.token", res.data.token, { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1, });
```

[image]
I perform a `Router.push('/home')`, when I arrive at the Home page I go through GetServerSideProps, which checks if this cookie exists so that it allows access to the home page.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const { ['nextauth.token']:token } = parseCookies(ctx)
  if(!token) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false
      }
    }
  }
  return { props: {} }
}
```

However, what happens is that after the redirect this `token` is `undefined` and only after performing an F5, the token is found. Which doesn't make much sense because the token was added before `Router.push('/home')`, My hypothesis is that the `undefined` in the first parameter of `setCookie` is registering in the ClientSide and when performing the first loading home this cookie is not there yet. Can someone please help me